# Passing multiple data to a bootstrap modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-modal

I want to pass multiple data to a bootstrap modal, Is it possible to pass?. I found only single `data(ISBN564541)` passing. Here is code

Modal HTML

```
<p>Link 1</p>
<a data-toggle="modal" data-id="ISBN564541" title="Add this item" class="open-AddBookDialog btn btn-primary" href="#addBookDialog">test</a>

<div class="modal hide" id="addBookDialog">
 <div class="modal-header">
    <button class="close" data-dismiss="modal">×</button>
    <h3>Modal header</h3>
  </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        <p>some content</p>
        <input type="text" name="bookId" id="bookId" value=""/>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS

```
$(document).on("click", ".open-AddBookDialog", function () {
     var myBookId = $(this).data('id');
     $(".modal-body #bookId").val( myBookId );
});
```

Please reply.

Comment: You can pass everything you like in a modal, it is just an HTML document. I think you will need to learn a little more about how you can close, open and handle modals first.

Answer (score 0):

You could put your extra data in an object like this:

```
var books = {
  'ISBN564541': {
    'title': 'Book 1',
    'pages': 256
  },
  'ABCDEF': {
    'title': 'Book 2',
    'pages': 1024
  }
};
```

Then in your click function you can retrive the extra data using the book id to set the values of any input tag:

```
var book = books[myBookId];
$(".modal-body #bookTitle").val( book.title );
$(".modal-body #bookPages").val( book.pages );
```